# Issues with Python / Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

```
import contextlib
with contextlib.redirect_stdout(None):
    import pygame
    import os
    import time
# Define some colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
z = 0
b = 0
h= 0

pygame.init()
image = []
path = 'E:\Andrew Photos'
pub= open("public.txt","w+")
now = open("nowhere.txt","w+")
sch = open("school.txt","w+")
files = []
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.jpg' in file:
            files.append(os.path.join(r, file))
            print (file)
public = []
school = []
nowhere = []
# Set the width and height of the screen [width, height]
size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0),pygame.FULLSCREEN)
x, y = screen.get_size() 
pygame.display.set_caption("Testy Testerson")

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False
i =0
# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
click = 0
# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
      x, y = screen.get_size() 
      while i < len(files):
            mousex, mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
          # --- Main event loop
            for event in pygame.event.get():
              if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                  done = True
            # if any mouse button is pressed pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP
              if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    click = 0
              if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                # if the left button is pressed

                if event.button == 1:
                      if mousex >= x-50: 
                            if mousey <= 30:
                                  exit(1)
                                  pygame.quit()
                                  done = True


                      if mousex >= x-300:
                            if mousey >= y-100:
                                  nowhere.append(files[i])
                                  now.write(files[i])
                                  i = i +1

                      elif mousex <= 300:
                            if mousey >=y-100:
                                  pub.write(files[i])
                                  i = i+1
                                  public.append(files[i-1])

                      elif mousex <=800:
                            if mousex >= 1100:
                                  if mousey >= y-100:
                                        school.append(files[i])
                                        sch.write(files[i])
                                        i = 1 +1


                      click = 1
                      if i == len(files):
                            pygame.QUIT()
          # --- Game logic should go here

          # --- Screen-clearing code goes here


          # Here, we clear the screen to white. Don't put other drawing commands
          # above this, or they will be erased with this command.

          # If you want a background image, replace this clear with blit'ing the
          # background image.
            screen.fill(WHITE)
            if i >= len(files):
                  pygame.QUIT
            #pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED,(x-50,0,50,30))
            if i < len(files):
                  image = pygame.image.load(files[i])
            screen.blit(image, (0,0))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED,(x-300,y-100,300,100))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN,(0,y-100,300,100))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLUE,(800,y-100,300,100))
          # --- Drawing code should go here
         #   i = 0
       #     while i < len(files):

       #           image = pygame.image.load(files[i])
       #           screen.blit(image, (0,0))

       #           pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED,(x-300,y-100,300,100))
       #           pygame.display.flip()
       #           if mousex >= x-300:
        #                if mousey >= y-100:
         #                     if click == 1:
          #                          nowhere.append(files[i])
           #                         time.sleep(1)
            #                        if click == 0:
             #                             i = i+1



          # --- Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
            pygame.display.flip()

          # --- Limit to 60 frames per second

# Close the window and quit.
            clock.tick(60)

pygame.QUIT()
exit()
```

I am trying to make it so when you click the squares at the bottom, it adds to three separate text files the name of the file that went to each box, but im having some issues, and ive been able to figure out most of them, but cant fix them.

The first click does not work.
The blue rectangle does not function, at all
Nothing ends up in the files at all. I would settle for all of them in the same file with a header and a gap between lists.

Currently i am using 4 random JPG.s to do this, but the goal is to make it so i can sort 2,000 of them.

Comment: I dont like the 2 while loops. you could just have `while not done` and have a `if i >= len(files): done = true`

Comment: Also could you explain what does work? I would suggest putting print statement throughout it to figure out what part isn't working.

Comment: @TheBigKahuna it was there, it seems someone removed it?
The first click in abox is nonfunctional regardless of what box is used. 
The blue box doesnt work when clicked.
It is not outputting to files. And honestly i thought i had removed while not done

Comment: Ive copied and pasted your code, changed it to one loop and got rid of the images and file writing and the buttons were working. So try one loop mabye

Comment: I did the same, but for some reason the middle button is still non fuctional for me. 

I dont know whats causing that conditional to not be true @TheBigKahuna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright. so i was in windowed mode instead of fullscreen, but i think the problem was a mistake in the if statements, you had a '<' around the wrong way

this works

```
                if mousex >= x-300:
                    if mousey >= y-100:
                        print("red")
                        i = i +1

                elif mousex <= 300:
                    if mousey >=y-100:
                        print("green")
                        i += 1

                elif mousex >=500:
                    if mousex <= 800:
                        if mousey >= y-100: # this was also 1100 which doesnt help
                            print("blue")
                            i = 1 +1
```

i changed the locations of the buttons as they were going off my screen so this is what i had

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED,(x-300,y-100,300,100))
pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN,(0,y-100,300,100))
pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLUE,(500,y-100,300,100))
```

Comment: That fixes that issue, I should be able to fix the error with file output now, thanks so much! <3